# O que é XGH (Extreme Go Horse)?

Tags: terminologia

Vejo algumas pessoas do meio da programação se referindo a esse termo sempre que aparece um código com uma solução estranha ou meio "*engambiarrada*".

Dando uma pesquisada rápida no Google, eu cheguei a conclusão de que realmente é isso.

Achei os termos *Go Horse Process* e *Extreme Go Horse*.

O que achei estranho é que, em alguns artigos que falam sobre *Go Horse Process*, apareceu também vários tópicos de *"como fazer"* (22 itens) e ainda foi chamado de "metodologia".

Mas do que realmente isso se trata?

É realmente uma metodologia, ou uma piada, ou uma forma hilária de se listar aquilo que deve ser evitado na programação?

Comment: [Descricao do XGH](http://www.guj.com.br/t/extreme-go-horse-programming/18806)

Comment: Relacionado? O link aponta para um site externo...

Comment: É basicamente uma piada. Na forma normalmente divulgada não serve pra muita coisa, poderiam fazer de um jeito útil e bem humorado. Não vou responder e vamos ver se a comunidade aceita bem a pergunta ou trata como algo inútil. Um tonto fez uma pergunta próxima no SE.SE: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7217/389

Comment: Acredito que essa forma de trabalhar já existia, mas não havia um nome ainda. Depois que esta se tornou mais comum no mundo da programação devido a vários motivos, essa forma de trabalhar ganhou um nome: Extreme Go Horse. Passou a ser uma metodologia muito usada, em diversas áreas. Parece piada, mas é verdade. Igual a piada que fazem com o Palmeiras não ter mundial. É piada ? Sim. Mas é verdade.

Comment: @bigown não sei se é inútil. Toda hora vejo alguém no chat falando que "fez um XGH" :p

Comment: É piada. A Internet está cheia dessas coisas, exemplo [Programming Motherf\*uck\*r](http://programming-motherfucker.com/) e [Gambi Design Patterns](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns).

Comment: Até agora só vi uma piada no site. Estou deixando, estou esperando outros se manifestarem, mas pra mim é mesma coisa ou pior que http://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/221800

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque acho que é uma pergunta **não construtiva**, abre espaço para respostas baseadas em opiniões e discussões desnecessárias.

Comment: Com certeza é uma metodologia real. Eu vejo adeptos o tempo todo, inclusive aqui no site.

Comment: Se é útil para o site é algo bastante discutível, mas que pelo menos faz refletir e dar umas boas risadas, isso não tem a menor dúvida. Pela atenção que esse tipo de pergunta recebe, creio que deve ser mantida. Aliás, já aguardo ansiosamente a resposta do @OnoSendai.

Comment: Não fechem a pergunta, o *mestre da programação* quer dar uma resposta :p

Comment: Sou contra o fechamento dessa pergunta e já aviso que se for fechada, votarei para reabrir.

Comment: Nesse momento, talvez seria legal o posicionamento de quem está votando negativo, já que existem votos positivos tanto nas respostas como na pergunta. Seria interessante ter um respaldo para gente poder entender o que há de errado com a pergunta. O "não gostar" não me parece um motivo para isso (não que eu esteja dizendo que os votos foram nesse sentido, mas em todos os casos, o feedback é bem-vindo)

Comment: No meu ver, a pergunta é válida. XGH é um termo relacionado à programação.  Se essa pergunta não é construtiva, acho que a que eu fiz do 'Brainfuck' também deveria cair nesse mesmo ponto.

Comment: Essa pergunta está perguntando "*O que é XGH?*", e não "*me deem exemplos de XGH*" e nem "*qual o melhor/pior caso de XGH que você já viu?*" - Assim sendo, ela **não é** uma pergunta opinativa, nem ampla demais e nem uma *poll question*. Ela de fato é uma pergunta objetiva, específica, clara e dentro do escopo do site, e portanto deveria ser mantida aberta.

Comment: A pergunta acabou de aparecer na [fila de analise](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/87276), eu votei para deixar ela aberta, é uma pergunta interessante e já dei estrelinha e +1. Eu gosto da metodologia XGH e o site esta com vários exemplos onde este padrão é aplicado em perguntas e respostas (não é todas é claro). Sejamos todos horse! :P

Comment: Seria legal quem passou dando -1 em todas as respostas também justificasse. Com uma sequência tão radical, parece até que as respostas estão todas erradas :p

Comment: Concordo com o Victor, a pergunta não tem nada de opinativa, GoHorse é algo que "existe", e apesar de ser uma critica as metodologias e "ambientes de trabalho", ainda sim é algo bem descrito e não tem opinião A ou B, se alguém explicar que não é uma *sátira* (brincadeira, critica, piada, etc) é porque não entendeu o que é de fato GoHorse e isto não é caso de opinião e sim falta de conhecimento.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5447/132

Comment: Uma musiquinha que explica o processo: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htqIhjhtDBM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htqIhjhtDBM)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

O *Go Horse* ou *Go Horse Process* é uma crítica mostrada de maneira a satirizar o mau-uso de certas "metodologias", assim como as "metodologias ágeis", ou nenhum uso delas. Ele na verdade é uma crítica ao que muitos desenvolvedores costumam fazer. Mesmo alguns com mais experiência têm momentos de:

- Preguiça/relaxo.
- Não se preocupar com correções ou melhoramentos futuros, pois acreditam que aquilo é definitivo.
- Se preocupar com prazo, mas não com o funcionamento ou segurança.
- Tudo isso geralmente acompanhado de gambiarras.

Entenda que o *Go Horse* (e o *e**X**treme **G**o **H**orse*) não é algo para ser feito, é algo que se você vai ler e vai servir para entender que o **não deve fazer**, como disse antes é uma crítica ao que muitos desenvolvedores acabam por fazer.

- *Go Horse* = vai cavalo
- *Go Horse Process* = processo "vai cavalo"
- *eXtreme Go Horse* = vai cavalo extremo

*Vai cavalo* não tem significado algum direto, ele provavelmente se refere a corrida de cavalos.

Como citado nas demais respostas, o site original foi encerrado. Todavia, tinha um grupo em português que se atualizava e ainda estão ativos.

> Os autores Ornado e Mário Marolo deixaram uma nota de despedida http://www.gohorseprocess.com.br/adeus-ou-ate-logo-quem-sabe (com um pitada de humor).

Link http://www.gohorseprocess.com.br/extreme-go-horse-(xgh) da lista completa:

> 1. **Pensou, não é XGH.**
>
>    XGH não pensa, faz a primeira coisa que vem à mente. Não existe
>      segunda opção, a única opção é a mais rápida.
> 2. **Existem 3 formas de se resolver um problema, a correta, a errada e a XGH, que é igual à errada, só que mais rápida.**
>
>    XGH é mais rápido que qualquer metodologia de desenvolvimento de
>      software que você conhece (Vide Axioma 14).
> 3. **Quanto mais XGH você faz, mais precisará fazer.**
>
>    Para cada problema resolvido usando XGH, mais uns 7 são criados. Mas
>      todos eles serão resolvidos da forma XGH. XGH tende ao infinito.
> 4. **XGH é totalmente reativo.**
>
>    Os erros só existem quando aparecem.
> 5. **XGH vale tudo, só não vale dar o ****.**
>
>    Resolveu o problema? Compilou? Commit e era isso.
> 6. **Commit sempre antes de update.**
>
>    Se der merda, a sua parte estará sempre correta e seus colegas que
>      se *****.
> 7. **XGH não tem prazo.**
>
>    Os prazos passados pelo seu cliente são meros detalhes. Você SEMPRE
>      conseguirá implementar TUDO no tempo necessário (nem que isso implique
>      em acessar o BD por um script maluco).
> 8. **Esteja preparado para pular fora quando o barco começar a afundar... ou coloque a culpa em alguém ou algo.**
>
>    Pra quem usa XGH, um dia o barco afunda. Quanto mais o tempo passa,
>      mais o sistema vira um monstro. O dia que a casa cair, é melhor seu
>      curriculum estar cadastrado na APInfo, ou ter algo pra colocar a
>      culpa.
> 9. **Seja autêntico, XGH não respeita padrões.**
>
>    Escreva o código como você bem entender, se resolver o problema,
>      commit e era isso.
> 10. **Não existe refactoring, apenas rework.**
>
>     Se der merda, refaça um XGH rápido que solucione o problema. O dia que
>       o rework implicar em reescrever a aplicação toda, pule fora, o barco
>       irá afundar (Vide Axioma 8).
> 11. **XGH é totalmente anárquico.**
>
>     A figura de um gerente de projeto é totalmente descartável. Não tem
>       dono, cada um faz o que quiser na hora que os problemas e requisitos
>       vão surgindo (Vide Axioma 4).
> 12. **Se iluda sempre com promessas de melhorias.**
>
>     Colocar TODO no código como uma promessa de melhoria ajuda o
>       desenvolvedor XGH a não sentir remorso ou culpa pela ****** que fez. É
>       claro que o refactoring nunca será feito (Vide Axioma 10).
> 13. **XGH é absoluto, não se prende à coisas relativas.**
>
>     Prazo e custo são absolutos, qualidade é totalmente relativa. Jamais
>       pense na qualidade e sim no menor tempo que a solução será
>       implementada, aliás… não pense, faça!
> 14. **XGH é atemporal.**
>
>     Scrum, XP… tudo isso é modinha. O XGH não se prende às modinhas do
>       momento, isso é coisa de *****. XGH sempre foi e sempre será usado por
>       aqueles que desprezam a qualidade.
> 15. **XGH nem sempre é POG.**
>
>     Muitas POG’s exigem um raciocínio muito elevado, XGH não raciocina
>       (Vide Axioma 1).
> 16. **Não tente remar contra a maré.**
>
>     Caso seus colegas de trabalho usam XGH para programar e você é um
>       coxinha que gosta de fazer as coisas certinhas, esqueça! Pra cada
>       Design Pattern que você usa corretamente, seus colegas gerarão 10
>       vezes mais código podre usando XGH.
> 17. **O XGH não é perigoso até surgir um pouco de ordem.**
>
>     Este axioma é muito complexo, mas sugere que o projeto utilizando XGH
>       está em meio ao caos. Não tente por ordem no XGH (Vide Axioma 16), é
>       inútil e você pode jogar um tempo precioso no lixo. Isto fará com que
>       o projeto afunde mais rápido ainda (Vide Axioma 8). Não tente
>       gerenciar o XGH, ele é auto suficiente (Vide Axioma 11), assim como o
>       caos.
> 18. **O XGH é seu brother, mas é vingativo.**
>
>     Enquanto você quiser, o XGH sempre estará do seu lado. Mas cuidado,
>       não o abandone. Se começar um sistema utilizando XGH e abandoná-lo
>       para utilizar uma metodologia da moda, você estará ******. O XGH não
>       permite refactoring (vide axioma 10), e seu novo sistema cheio de
>       frescurites entrará em colapso. E nessa hora, somente o XGH poderá
>       salvá-lo.
> 19. **Se tiver funcionando, não rela a mão.**
>
>     Nunca altere, e muito menos questione um código funcionando. Isso é
>       perda de tempo, mesmo porque refactoring não existe (Vide Axioma 10).
>       Tempo é a engrenagem que move o XGH e qualidade é um detalhe
>       desprezível.
> 20. **Teste é para os fracos.**
>
>     Se você meteu a mão num sistema XGH, é melhor saber o que está
>       fazendo. E se você sabe o que está fazendo, vai testar pra que? Testes
>       são desperdício de tempo, se o código compilar, é o suficiente.
> 21. **Acostume-se ao sentimento de fracasso iminente.**
>
>     O fracasso e o sucesso andam sempre de mãos dadas, e no XGH não é
>       diferente. As pessoas costumam achar que as chances do projeto
>       fracassar utilizando XGH são sempre maiores do que ele ser bem
>       sucedido. Mas sucesso e fracasso são uma questão de ponto de vista. O
>       projeto foi por água abaixo mas você aprendeu algo? Então pra você foi
>       um sucesso!
> 22. **O problema só é seu quando seu nome está no Doc da classe.**
>
>     Nunca ponha a mão numa classe cujo autor não é você. Caso um membro da
>       equipe morra ou fique doente por muito tempo, o barco irá afundar!
>       Nesse caso, utilize o Axioma 8.

Comment: Boa resposta. Alguém que realmente entende do assunto :p

Comment: Nesse caso "alguém que realmente entende do assunto" é um elogio ou uma ofensa? :p

Comment: @renan nenhum dos dois hehehe, quero dizer o problema GHP não é nem sempre culpa do desenvolvedor, pode ser culpa da equipe inteira de desenvolvimento e até da equipe e dos "acionistas", eu mesmo vivo isto, não porque eu desejo, mas devido as "necessidades" da empresa, que nos "forçam" a trabalhar assim. Tentei organizar de várias maneiras, mas sem aprovação dos superiores e excessiva cobrança por menores prazos, má vontade em entregarem os requisitos e acharem que podemos estipular prazos em 5 minutos acabamos sendo forçado a usar o "GHP" . Então digamos que eu entendo, mas não porque quero.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento **11: XGH é totalmente anárquico.**. Se está em um nível hierárquico, você está utilizando errado. :p

Comment: _"Vai cavalo provavelmente vem da corrida de cavalos"_ - eu interpreto de uma forma parecida mas um pouco diferente, penso que vem do ato de dar com a espora no lombo do cavalo, ou seja, evoluir um projeto na base dos trancos e barrancos, uma coisa forçada, sem cuidado.

Comment: @Piovezan faz muito mais sentido que o que eu imaginava, vou revisar a resposta assim que possivel. Obrigado

Comment: 1 pessoa não gostou da "metologia" **go horse**

Comment: Não entendi, porque deram downvote na minha resposta, mas não na dos demais (se é que a pessoa é contra responder esta pergunta), só consigo presumir que a pessoa tenha achado algum problema na resposta, PODERIA JUSTIFICAR comentando aqui por favor?

Comment: E ainda lembrando que com XGH utizamos muito TDD: Teste Depois do Deploy ... quando testado.

Comment: PERFEITO, outro downvote sem justificativa e só na minha resposta. Tem gente que não sabe votar.

Comment: Pra mim, o termo "vai cavalo" vem dos carroceiros, que chicoteiam os cavalos gritando "Vai cavalo!": o pobre animal só enxerga o que está imediatamente a frente, e tudo que pode fazer é seguir adiante, puxando um peso enorme e desconhecido, sem saber p/onde está indo ou quanto falta p/chegar. Seria uma analogia ao programador que está sobrecarregado de tarefas e com os prazos em cima, sendo pressionado pelo gerente; incapaz de seguir uma metodologia decente, faz o que dá e segue p/próxima tarefa, sempre resolvendo o problema mais imediato, sem saber p/onde está indo ou quanto falta p/chegar.

Comment: @msb interessante analogia! Nas corridas de cavalos é semelhante.

Comment: exceto que na corrida de cavalo, o cavalo nao esta sobrecarregado; a carroca geralmente sim, e os devs XGH tb. E a corrida acaba rapido, ao contrario da carroca que passa o dia todo carregando peso numa tarefa sem fim, assim como o desenvolvimento XGH (ver axioma 3). ;) mas na corrida, a pressao eh maior. (y)

Comment: @msd sim, na corrida ele tem que correr feito um louco sem entender a motivação, mas o maior principio é chegar ao final, independente do cavalo ou cavaleiro, a questão é chegue até o final, não importa como (mas é apenas o que eu entendi nos artigos que li).

Answer (score 64):

[image: Ensō, o símbolo da iluminação, força, elegância, o universo e o vazio]

<sub>Assim disse o Mestre Programador: *Quando um programa está em fase de testes, é muito tarde para se realizar mudanças de escopo.*</sub>

---

Diz a lenda que em uma longínqua província havia um monastério onde o Mestre Programador compartilhava seus ensinamentos. Um de seus diálogos foi a respeito das práticas do infame engenheiro da corte Xingh, e os acontecimentos que circundaram a construção das Duas Pontes.

---

'*Mestre*', dialogou um dos arquitetos da corte de Tang, '*Nós começamos os trabalhos da Ponte Norte do Rio Amarelo seguindo seus veneráveis preceitos KISS, YAGNI e DRY, que são os verdadeiros pilares que sustentam nossa estrutura.*

*Porém recentemente o Imperador tem se mostrado bastante impressionado com a eficiência da equipe de Mestre Xingh, que aparentemente ignora todos os preceitos dos antigos Mestres ao construir a Ponte Sul - ele não se preocupa com o equilíbrio e harmonia, ao invés disso reforçando as estruturas com o que tiver à mão.*

*Seus trabalhadores também são tratados como escravos - ondas de novatos vem e vão, exauridos e desgostosos. Porém ainda assim sua ponte se ergue, caótica até o ponto onde a estrutura é coberta, e sua aparência melhorada. Você acha que estamos perdendo muito tempo? Deveríamos abraçar o caos?*'

'*Seu coração é fraco, e sua resolução se esvai com a primeira brisa,*', disse o Mestre Programador. '*Procure sempre o equilíbrio, e utilize sempre os pilares dos antigos Mestres. Caos atrai caos; Harmonia atrai harmonia.*'

O Engenheiro, envergonhado pelas duras porém verdadeiras palavras, se retirou em silêncio para o campo onde a equipe de construção se reunia.

---

A Corte Imperial se reuniu para a inauguração das Pontes oito meses depois.

A Ponte Norte se erguia bela e delicada; o orgulho de seus artesãos, suas formas graciosas espelhadas no rio. Nada lhe faltava, nada lhe excedia.

A Ponte Sul, entretanto, tinha sido concluída quatro meses antes - e já contava com expansões que a tornavam várias vezes mais larga. Ao encontrar o Arquiteto da Ponte Norte junto ao Imperador, Mestre Xingh não conseguia conter seu fino sorriso de escárnio.

O Imperador, um homem de números, ouro e guerras, proferiu rasgados elogios a Mestre Xingh por sua eficiência. O Príncipe-Herdeiro, admirador dos Grandes Mestres, agradeceu profusamente ao Arquiteto pela nova jóia que adornava a cidade.

O Imperador montou em *Jíduān qù mǎ*, seu cavalo preferido, e se encaminhou para a Ponte Sul - ao mesmo tempo que o Príncipe-Herdeiro se encaminhou para a ponte Norte, montado em *Wěn*.

Todos se surpreenderam quando um estrondoso ruído oriundo da Ponte Sul, acompanhado de uma gigantesca nuvem de poeira e farpas de madeira, indicou o momento onde tanto a ponte quanto o Imperador se fizeram ao rio.

"*Alguém testou se a ponte aguentava cavalos?*" sussurrou em choque um dos descrédulos trabalhadores da Ponte Sul. Eles se entreolharam em silêncio.

O Príncipe, que já havia atravessado a Ponte Norte, cavalgou veloz até o local do acidente, suas lágrimas se tornando parte do rio ao encontrar o corpo alquebrado do Imperador. Neste momento o Mestre Programador se aproximou do agora Príncipe-Regente, e proferiu estas palavras:

"Que a dor de sua perda diminua com o tempo, porém nunca esqueça da lição aprendida aqui: Que KISS, YAGNI e DRY sejam os pilares de um longo e harmonioso reinado."

---

Daquela época muito já se foi e não existe mais.

Da Ponte Sul, apenas o infame termo 'como uma ponte de Xingh' restou - e muitos desconhecem sua origem. A natureza retomou as margens do rio, e mesmo sua pedra fundamental foi perdida.

Porém até hoje os visitantes da Cidade Imperial são recebidos pela Ponte Norte; inúmeras gerações de Imperadores passaram sob seus elegantes arcos, aos quais o tempo só dignidade adicionou. Tão altiva como no dia da sua inauguração, suas delicadas formas espelhadas no rio.

Comment: Poético... É assim mesmo que acontece nos dias atuais,,,E mais fácil de entender... Issa ae dá um curta metragem...

Comment: Eu gostaria de ser discípulo desse Mestre :p

Comment: *Ok, mas o que é XGH?*

Comment: O cavalo do Imperador. ;)

Comment: Mestre XinGH!  Muito bom!

Answer (score 20):

Go Horse é uma sátira sobre o desenvolvimento de software que basicamente é a junção de pessoas executando papéis e processos.

O *Extreme Go Horse* é a metodologia que sugere quais processos devem ser executados para se atingir as metas do projeto, onde praticamente a única métrica de qualidade é "está funcionando?".

É uma piada com fundo de verdade. Algumas situações ou recomendações parecem até tirinhas do [dilbert](http://dilbert.com/). Ela mostra que, mesmo com um ambiente caótico, nenhuma organização, realização de tarefas iguais (repetição) com resultados diferentes, pessoas incompetentes e geração de artefatos que não agregam valor nenhum. Sim, é possível construir software que funcione, atenda as necessidades do cliente e seja rentável.

Mais detalhes ácidos em: [gohorseprocess](http://www.gohorseprocess.com.br)

Comment: Perfeita descrição, esqueci de citar o "objetivo"

Answer (score 14):

Explicando melhor. Retirei do site do Hélio esse exemplo.

> *XGH é uma das coisas mais genias que surgiu nos últimos tempos, descrevendo a estupidez que se aplica em métodos ágeis, mas que reflete bem o ambiente corporativo.*
>
> **1- Pensou, não é XGH.** XGH não pensa, faz a primeira coisa que vem à mente. Não existe segunda opção, a única opção é a mais rápida.
>
> **2- Existem 3 formas de se resolver um problema, a correta, a errada e a XGH, que é igual à errada, só que mais rápida.** XGH é mais rápido que qualquer metodologia de desenvolvimento de software que você conhece (Vide Axioma 14).
>
> **3- Quanto mais XGH você faz, mais precisará fazer.** Para cada problema resolvido usando XGH, mais uns 7 são criados. Mas todos eles serão resolvidos da forma XGH. XGH tende ao infinito.

Então XGH é um "método" que é bastante utilizado hoje e sempre. Uma piada direcionada aos maus métodos (POG).

Veja mais em [EXtreme Go Horse - XGH](http://helio.loureiro.eng.br/index.php/pessoal/39-blog/240-extreme-go-horse-xgh)