# Imagens se sobrepondo quando resolução altera

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Tenho 4 imagens lado a lado, mas quando reajusto a resolução elas estão se sobrepondo uma a uma. Eu gostaria que elas se ajustassem mas permanecessem lado a lado já que a resolução permite a permanência delas

veja na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS

```css
.snip1566 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -10px;
  max-width: 190px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.snip1566 *,
.snip1566:before,
.snip1566:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.snip1566:before,
.snip1566:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius:60%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-color: transparent #bbb;
}

.snip1566 img {
  width: 120px;
  height:120px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;

   float: none;
    margin-right:-30px;
    width:auto;
   
}




.snip1566 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align:center; font-weight:bold; opacity:0.7;
}
.snip1566  .caption { position: absolute; width: 120px; height: 120px; top: 70%; left: 0px; color: #fff; text-align:center;
                       background: transparent; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-size:14px; opacity:0.7; }
.snip1566 i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 4em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.snip1566 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="alignme"><p class="to-animate intro-animate-3">
                                        </p>
                                        <figure class="snip1566">
  <img src="images/skillset/userexperience.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
<div class="caption"><br/>imagem um</div>
</figure>
 <figure class="snip1566">
  <img src="images/skillset/userinterface.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
  <div class="caption"><br/>imagem dois</div>
</figure>
                                               <figure class="snip1566">
  <img src="images/skillset/dev.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
  <div class="caption"><br/>imagem tres</div>
</figure>
                                         <figure class="snip1566">
  <img src="images/skillset/branding.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
 <div class="caption"><br/>imagem quatro</div>
</figure>
                                              <br />
                                             
        </div>
```

Comment: Não seria o `margin: -10px`  o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta não está clara, e se o caso não for a solução do comentário, ou seja se você quer que elas "continuem lado a lado"...

Seu html e css precisam ser reformulados...

Mas uma solução rápida([XGH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164124/o-que-%C3%A9-xgh-extreme-go-horse)) seria utilizar [media queries](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19342/como-trabalhar-com-media-queries-css):

```html
<div class="alignme">
 <p class="to-animate intro-animate-3">Blablbblala</p>
    <figure class="snip1566">
    <img src="images/skillset/userexperience.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
  <figcaption>imagem um</figcaption>
 </figure>
  <figure class="snip1566">
    <img src="images/skillset/userinterface.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
    <figcaption>imagem dois</figcaption>
 </figure>
    <figure class="snip1566">
    <img src="images/skillset/dev.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
    <figcaption>imagem tres</figcaption>
 </figure>
    <figure class="snip1566">
    <img src="images/skillset/branding.png" alt="sq-sample14" />
   <figcaption>imagem quatro</figcaption>
 </figure>
</div>
<style>
*{padding:0; margin:0;border:0;}
.snip1566{
 
  float:left;
  margin-left:40px;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.snip1566:before,
.snip1566:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.snip1566:before,
.snip1566:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius:60%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-color: transparent #bbb;
}
.snip1566 img {
display:block;
  
  width: 120px;
  height:120px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
figcaption{
 color: #black; text-align:center;
    background: transparent;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    opacity:0.7; }
@media(max-width:650px)
{
 .snip1566 img, .snip1566:before,
 .snip1566:after {width:60px;height:60px;}
 figcaption{width:60px;display: block;}

}
</style>
```

Fiz um exemplo com um `breakpoint`, aí você ajusta conforme sua necessidade.