# O que é considerado uma "gambiarra" ou um código mal feito?

Tags: terminologia, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome

Por exemplo, eu crio um código, e ele funciona, mas não tenho certeza que é correto eu fazer o mesmo daquele jeito. Isso é uma gambiarra? Eu tenho que ter certeza de que o código é feito de tal maneira pra ele se considerado um "bom código"?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é código spaghetti?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31315/64969)

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é XGH (Extreme Go Horse)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164124/64969)

Comment: Pessoal que tá votando pra fechar: vocês acham mesmo que o que separa uma gambiarra de algo bem feito é uma opinião? TI deixou de ser das exatas?

Comment: Quando eu vi a pergunta não vi motivo pra fechar.
Depois que vi o motivo(Principalmente baseada em opiniões) fiquei com uma pulga atras da orelha, mas gambiarra não deixa de ser uma solução mal feita, mal estruturada, ou mal elaborada, isso é universal, eu acho kk

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33702/101

Comment: Que a pergunta não é boa eu não tenho dúvidas, mas não sei com o que fechar. Tanto é ruim que a resposta postada, pode ser interessante mas não responde ao que foi perguntado. E não sei se dá pra responder aqui. Isso envolve muita coisa, me parece algo como ampla. Não é só dizer o que é gambiarra, tem que mostrar tudo o que é, envolve anos de experiência sendo passadas em algumas linhas, não dá.

Comment: Os links passados acho que vão esclarecer minha dúvida. Renan disse isso e votou pra fechar também, não entendi '-' "Pessoal que tá votando pra fechar: vocês acham mesmo que o que separa uma gambiarra de algo bem feito é uma opinião? TI deixou de ser das exatas?" Mas, obrigado, acho que ja posso também, ter, minha opinião!

Comment: Ah. São 2 Renan's, rs; Desculpe.

Comment: @bigown eu concordo com "ampla demais", mas não com "baseada em opiniões". P.s.: não sou o Renan que votou pra fechar.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta pode ajudar a esclarecer um pouco: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152237/14262, principalmente na parte **Legibilidade e manutenção**

Comment: O que vai definir se código é uma gambiarra é o contexto onde ela foi aplicada ou seja naquele cenário a solução adotada foi adequada? Entende por contexto o ambiente e o requisitos da funcionalidade/sistema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gambiarra é o termo utilizado para código de má qualidade e mal-feito, e que nem sempre funciona (mas às vezes funciona sim, só que de uma maneira que não deveria ser utilizada).

Frequentemente, trata-se de um código confuso, amarrado com um monte de coisa que pouco ou nada tem a ver com a finalidade do código, e traz problemas e efeitos colaterais indesejados. Pode também ser um código frágil que não funciona em situações anormais.

Por exemplo:

[image: Gambiarra]

Saber o que é ou não gambiarra é algo muito subjetivo. Um exemplo de uma gambiarra no mundo real da programação seria ao invés de passar um valor X como parâmetro da função A para a função B, salvar o X em um arquivo na função A e ler esse arquivo na função B. Isso é gambiarra porque o arquivo estaria sendo usado para a aplicação se comunicar com ela mesma sem estar salvando dados de uma execução para outra e nem economizando memória, e gera efeitos colaterais porque depende do uso do disco, é mais lento, etc. E também é uma forma inadequada de fazer, pois existe uma outra solução bem mais simples e direta e arquivos não foram concebidos com essa finalidade.

Comment: Mas ai, como vou chegar a essa conclusão? "maneira que não deveria ser utilizada" Será por isso que querem fechar a pergunta?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Editei a resposta.