# Corrigir JSON mal formatado

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regex

Recebo de um cliente um JSON totalmente fora do padrão. E, como sempre, o cliente tem sempre razão :-(

O JSON chega da seguinte maneira:

```
{ dominio:casadasloucas.com.br, wp-admin:casadasloucas.com.br/wp-admin, wp-user:fulano, wp-pass: 1234 }
```

Estou aplicando uma expressão regular que achei na WEB (pois sou péssimo em regex), que é a seguinte:

```
    jsonStr = re.sub("((?=\D)\w+):", r'"\1":',  jsonStr)
    jsonStr = re.sub(": ((?=\D)\w+)", r':"\1"',  jsonStr)
```

Mas ela acabou mais atrapalhando do que ajudando. O JSON, após aplicar a regex acima, ficou assim:

```
{ "dominio":"casadasloucas".com.br, wp-"admin":"casadasloucas".com.br/wp-admin, wp-"user":"fulano", wp-"pass": 1234 }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta expressão regular para que ela coloque as aspas corretamente?

Comment: Recomendo ler este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: Poderia explicar o que está tentando fazer? Verifiquei online, e o json fornecido parece um json válido, verifiquei neste site: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @Danizavtz Não é um JSON válido porque as chaves e valores devem estar entre aspas. O site que vc testou corrige o JSON (adicionando as aspas), mas se vc desmarcar a opção "Fix JSON", ele acusa como inválido. Testando em outros sites (como https://jsonlint.com) e no próprio Python, com o módulo `json`, vemos que de fato esses dados não formam um JSON válido. Enfim, o que se está tentando fazer na pergunta é colocar as aspas nos lugares certos para que o JSON fique válido

Answer (score 3):

**A solução ideal é corrigir o JSON na origem**. Quem envia os dados deve se certificar que eles estão no formato correto. Ponto. Qualquer outra solução (ainda mais com regex) será um paliativo não ideal (também conhecido como "remendo" ou "[gambiarra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164124/112052)").

Até porque o que você está recebendo não é um JSON (é algo que se parece com JSON, mas não segue a [sintaxe correta](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)), e nesse caso, o cliente **não** tem razão (mas entendo a "pressão" envolvida).

<sup>Ainda sim eu tentaria argumentar que mandar um "JSON" inválido é contraproducente para todos - inclusive para o próprio cliente - pois ao usar um formato não padronizado, isso consome mais tempo de desenvolvimento de quem vai ler, além de poder dar erros que não ocorreriam se o JSON estivesse correto. Usando o formato correto, todos ganham. Mas enfim, se ele não quer corrigir, que pelo menos fique ciente que ele também sofre as consequências...</sup>

Outro ponto é que [regex **não** é a ferramenta ideal para manipular um JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357086/112052) (embora [seja possível](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json), não é a melhor opção). Mesmo que sejam dados muito simples e "funcione", qualquer solução será muito propensa a erros e situações não-previstas, e no fim pode ser mais complicado do que simplesmente pedir que o cliente envie um JSON válido (sem contar o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052) adicional de se usar regex, pois dependendo do volume de dados, isso pode causar um problema de desempenho).

---

Dito isso, uma solução **bem** ingênua seria:

```
import re

jsonStr = "{ dominio:casadasloucas.com.br, wp-admin:casadasloucas.com.br/wp-admin, wp-user:fulano, wp-pass: 1234 }"
jsonStr = re.sub(r'([^ :]+)\s*:\s*([^ ,]+)', r'"\1": "\2"', jsonStr)
```

A regex assume que o nome das chaves são "qualquer coisa que não seja espaços nem dois-pontos": `[^ :]+`.

E os valores podem ser "qualquer coisa que não seja espaços nem vírgulas": `[^ ,]`.

Ou seja, estou me baseando no que *parece* ser a regra dos dados enviados (já que não foram dados mais detalhes, apenas um exemplo). Como não há aspas nos dados originais, entendo que não podem haver espaços ou vírgulas nos valores, pois aí a estrutura ficaria ambígua e muito mais difícil de analisar (mais um argumento a favor de mandar um JSON válido).

Com isso, a string se torna um JSON válido:

```js
{ "dominio": "casadasloucas.com.br", "wp-admin": "casadasloucas.com.br/wp-admin", "wp-user": "fulano", "wp-pass": "1234" }
```

Se quiser que os números não tenham aspas, você pode usar uma função de substituição:

```
def coloca_aspas(m):
    result = f'"{m.group(1)}": ' # nome da chave sempre entre aspas
    valor = m.group(2)
    try:
        int(valor) # verifica se o valor é número
        result += valor # se for, não coloca aspas
    except ValueError: # não é número, coloca entre aspas
        result += f'"{valor}"'
    return result

import re

jsonStr = re.sub(r'([^ :]+)\s*:\s*([^ ,]+)', coloca_aspas, jsonStr)
```

Com isso, o JSON fica assim:

```js
{ "dominio": "casadasloucas.com.br", "wp-admin": "casadasloucas.com.br/wp-admin", "wp-user": "fulano", "wp-pass": 1234 }
```

A sua regex não funcionou porque o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` considera apenas letras, números e o caractere `_`, então ele ignorava os caracteres como o ponto, barra e hífen. Por isso não deu o resultado esperado.

E o [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\D)` só verifica se o caractere seguinte não é um dígito. Nada que ajude muito na colocação das aspas nos lugares certos.

---

## Não use regex

Mas como já dito, essa solução é bem ingênua. Não sei se todos os valores possíveis são exatamente da forma que defini (pode ter valores com aspas, dois-pontos, espaços, chaves?), e nem se podem ter casos mais complicados que exigiriam uma mudança na regex (não testei com objetos e arrays aninhados, por exemplo). Se for o caso, provavelmente você teria que [construir seu próprio *parser* customizado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2036236), já que o módulo `json` não serve para ler formatos-que-se-parecem-mas-não-são-JSON.

Comment: Concordo com vc, mas o cliente não concorda conosco :-)

Sua RE quase funcionou... quando apliquei, a conversão ficou assim:
"{ dominio": "casadasloucas.com.br"", wp-admin": "casadasloucas.com.br/wp-admin"", wp-user": "fulano"", wp-pass": "1234"", cloudflare": "sim } "

Vou testar sua função... Obrigado!